# Why Auth0 verification is too short?

Tags: oauth-2.0, auth0

I am trying to incorporate Auth0 into my web application user login. However, I always get "Invalid verification code format.".

I notice the verification code provided by the Auth0Lock is `RRvIpXXXXXcpbWnw` while the one returned by a direct GET to `www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth` is much much much larger.

The question is: With Auth0, how should I use the verification code to exchange for the access_token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at - https://auth0.com/docs/protocols

Depending on the type of client you have - application with server side / ( trusted client) or untrusted or SPA you can decide which flow to use.

If you choose to use the authorization code grant flow. Please use the code and the other information such as clientid and secret to post to the oauth/token endpoint from your server side code to retrieve the access_token and the id_token(if scope is specified). See below:

POST https://tenant.auth0.com/oauth/token

Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE&grant_type=authorization_code&scope=openid...

From the response, you can use  id_token to call your own protected API and access_token to call auth0 API to get profile data etc.

If you are using implicit flow you can get the access_token and the id_token (jwt) in one call to the authorization endpoint.

The The client is never verified in the implicit flow.

Comment: Thank you! I found the document some time after I posted the question. I mistook the verification code of Auth0 with that of Facebook.